# Best location for a debugging script

Tags: debug

I am integrating Sentry.io into my multisite setup. I have 5 themes and a number of plugins across the network too.

Sentry needs to be initialised as early as possible, I want it to be loaded before the plugins so it can track issues with the plugins too. Where is the best place to insert the following:

> To capture all errors, even the one during the startup of your
>   application, you should initialize the Sentry PHP SDK as soon as
>   possible.

```
Sentry\init(['dsn' => 'https://123456789@sentry.io/123456789' ]);
```

As mentioned, I have multiple themes, so I don't suspect putting this line in each theme is correct.

Comment: Could you include it into wp-config.php? Earliest way to load it in a file that won’t be affected by updates.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe as a [must-use plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/)?

From docs,

> - Always-on, no need to enable via admin and users cannot disable by    accident.
> - Can be enabled simply by uploading file to the mu-plugins directory, without having to log-in.
> - Loaded by PHP, in alphabetical order, **before normal plugins**, meaning API hooks added in an mu-plugin apply to all other plugins
>     even if they run hooked-functions in the global namespace.